# Javascript random function changing the picture in the html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to ask for help completing this homework. Now, before you turn away , i am not asking anyone to write anything for me. I just need someone to point me in the right direction.

So, i need to create a dice game. My problem is that i am having problems finding a way to connect Javascript code to my Dices in the HTML file.

For example:

If the code :

```
var dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);
```

gives me say 4, then i would like for it to show my dice_4.png picture.

This is the code for the cube/dice on the html file.

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And on my css file.

```
.front {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_1.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
.back {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_6.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
.right {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_4.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
.left {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_3.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
.top {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_2.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
.bottom {
  background-image: url('Pildid/dice_5.png');
  background-size:100%;
}
```

I used a 3D cube without the rotation.

To recap, when random gives me say 4 for the first cube, i want the html to show me the `.right` part of the css file.

Not sure how much sense i am making here, will try to explain better if this is too confusing.

Does anyone have any ideas where i should look?

(Sorry, the format is a little messed up but its my first time and whatnot).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you have to do that in 3D or 2D will be ok too? and by the way it is `var dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);` 0,1,2,3,4,5 not `var dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 6);`  0,1,2,3,4,5,6

Comment: can you make a fiddle for us so we can understand this a bit better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to keep exactly the same HTML arrangement you have:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then you need some way to associate dice numbers to cube side div's. I would suggest an array of class names.

```
var dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
var sides = ['front', 'top', 'left', 'right', 'bottom', 'back'];
var cubeSides = document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0].children;
for (var i = 0; i < cubeSides.length; i++) {
  // If you only have a class associated to the cube side div's.
  cubeSides[i].style.display = cubeSides[i].className === sides[dice1] ? 'block' : 'none';
  // If you can have more than one class in the side div's, use this statement instead of the previous one.
  // cubeSides[i].style.display = cubeSides[i].className.split(' ').indexOf(sides[dice1]) > -1 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pc7rL9z6/).

But, if it is allowed to change the HTML structure to arrange the `div`'s in ascending order:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="cube">
    <div class="front"></div>
    <div class="top"></div>
    <div class="left"></div>
    <div class="right"></div>
    <div class="bottom"></div>
    <div class="back"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

then the code becomes easier:

```
var dice1 = Math.round(Math.random() * 5);
var cubeSides = document.getElementsByClassName('cube')[0].children;
for (var i = 0; i < cubeSides.length; i++) {
  cubeSides[i].style.display = i === dice1 ? 'block' : 'none';
}
```

See [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/w2k7cfs5/).

Answer (score 0):

```js
var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1;
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = number;
var image = 'url(Pildid/dice_'+number +'.png)';
document.getElementById('image').innerHTML = image;
// apply
document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].style.backgroundImage=image;
```

```html
<p id="demo"></p>
<div id="image"></div>
<div class="image"></div>
```

Comment: use `var number = Math.round(Math.random() * 5) + 1;` or `Math.floor(Math.random() * 6) + 1;`

Comment: what was I thinking, I will change